# react: disable right click on videojs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router, video.js

The following is my code:
I need to add a quality selector and disable the right-click option in a webpage which uses videojs. I am not sure on how to use the plugins, there weren't any examples of plugins in react. Please help

**VideoPlayer.js**

````
import videojs from "video.js";

export const VideoPlayer = (props) => {
  const videoPlayerRef = useRef(null); // Instead of ID
  const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(null);
  const videoSrc = "https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer_hd.mp4";

  const videoJSOptions = {
    autoplay: "muted",
    controls: true,
    userActions: { hotkeys: true },
    playbackRates: [0.5, 1, 1.5, 2],
    chromecast: {
      appId: "APP-ID",
      metadata: {
        title: "Title display on tech wrapper",
        subtitle: "Synopsis display on tech wrapper",
      },
    },
    hlsQualitySelector: {
      displayCurrentQuality: true,
    },
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (videoPlayerRef) {
      const player = videojs(videoPlayerRef.current, videoJSOptions, () => {
        player.src(videoSrc);
        player.on("ended", () => {
          console.log("ended");
        });
        player.on("timeupdate", () => {
          setCurrentTime(player.currentTime());
        });
        console.log("Player Ready");
      });
    }

    return () => {};
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={{ width: "100%" }}>
      <video
        style={{ width: "100%" }}
        ref={videoPlayerRef}
        className="video-js"
      />
      <span>Current Time: {currentTime}</span>
      {/* <GlobalStyle /> */}
    </div>
  );
};```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `onContextMenu` event prop to handle right clicks on a particular element. Something like this -

```
...
  return (
    <div onContextMenu={e => e.preventDefault()} style={{ width: "100%" }}>
      <video
        style={{ width: "100%" }}
        ref={videoPlayerRef}
        className="video-js"
      />
      <span>Current Time: {currentTime}</span>
      {/* <GlobalStyle /> */}
    </div>
  );
...
```

This will disable right click on the element and all the elements inside it. Also, this is only going to work with native HTML elements, unless you are forwarding the `onContextMenu prop` or `forwarding ref` for the HTML element.

Answer (score 3):

To disable right click menu in videoPlayer, you can use the `contextmenu` synthetic event in react,

```
document.addEventListener("contextmenu", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
});

// using react synthetic events
<SomeJSXVideoDOM onContextMenu={(event)=>event.preventDefault()} />
```

For more information, check out this [blog on contextmenu(https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-create-a-right-click-menu-using-react).

You can find more information on react synthetic event for onContextMenu over [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#mouse-events)